# Is there a way to dynamically update records based on values in one column and using that value to find a matching column name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

| Id | Codes | Col_Code1 | Col_Code2 | Col_Code3 | Col_Code4 | Col_Code5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A283240 | Code1 | 1 | Null | Null | Null | Null |
| B490382 | Code2 | Null | 1 | Null | Null | Null |
| B490382 | Code4 | Null | Null | Null | 1 | Null |
| B449200 | Code3 | Null | Null | 1 | Null | Null |
| C243456 | Code4 | Null | Null | Null | 1 | Null |
| C243456 | Code5 | Null | Null | Null | Null | 1 |

I'll try to explain this well. I have this report output. This is a small sample. It has about 440k rows and 7000 columns. I am aware of sql server's column restriction. I think I am going to append several tables together but this is the set up for each one. It is for medical data so our customer needs it reported this way. I need to take each ID in the first column read their respective codes, take the value of that code and update the corresponding column name that partially contains the name of the code. So for the 2nd record Col_Code2 needs to be updated with a "1" to flag that record as having a positive code 2. There are too many different codes, well there's over 7000 different ones, to update manually. I sense dynamic sql and a cursor and I am light on the dynamic sql. I have also heard I should fear cursors? Please provide any insight. Thanks.

### Update to my question as suggested. Sorry it wasn't clear enough.

Ok sorry guys. Maybe by a couple of examples. For every ID, take "B490382" who has two records. This person has a Code2 and a Code4. I want to take the Code2 since there is a value there and update Col_Code2 with a "1". Same w/ the record with Code4 for the same person. I need to program it to look up the Col_Code4 column on that row for the same member and again mark a "1". I'm trying to put together a dynamic script using information_schema.columns for example to match on the column names substring "Code2", "Code4" etc on that portion of the field name that matches the code. It will match the "Code2" part of "Col_Code2" and update for that ID.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to have a table with ID, Code and Value columns and then you can build the report with a pivot.
The column Vale isn't even needed if you have the single value 1.

| Id | Code | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A283240 | Code1 | 1 |
| B490382 | Code2 | 1 |
| B490382 | Code4 | 1 |
| B449200 | Code3 | 1 |
| C243456 | Code4 | 1 |
| C243456 | Code5 | 1 |

Pivot: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: My suggestion is to do a step back. You are going in wrong way. For this you're facing a problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a really horrible way to store data, and your question clearly demonstrates one of the reasons why.  Do [what MBuschi has suggested](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/318159/6965), so that you can use a regular `UPDATE` statement like this:

```
UPDATE
  dbo.MyCodeTable
SET
  Value = @Value
WHERE
  Id = @Id
  AND Code = @Code
;
```

Pivot the data only when requested.  Even better, leave the pivoting to the presentation layer.  I may be wrong but I suspect your insistence on having it this way might have something to do with an attempt to match the storage format with the presentation format, which, while a bad idea regardless, might not be *too* bad if you had a couple dozen codes at most.  At 7000+ codes, however, it is clear that the approach does not scale well.

However, if you are sure you absolutely must do it this way, and assuming that the input is still the same as in the above `UPDATE` (`@Id`, `@Code`, `@Value`), we can use that statement as a starting point for our dynamic `UPDATE`.  The thing that needs to be changed dynamically there is the name of the updated column.  Instead of `Value` it should be generated as `'Col_' + Code`.  With that in mind, the dynamic version could look like this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
  UPDATE
    dbo.MyCodeTable
  SET
    ' + QUOTENAME('Col_' + @Code) + ' = @Value
  WHERE
    Id = @Id
    AND Code = @Code
  ;'
;

EXECUTE
  sp_executesql
    @sql
  , N'@Id varchar(50)
    , @Code varchar(50)
    , @Value varchar(50)'  -- replace the data types with actual ones
  , @Id
  , @Code
  , @Value
;
```